# How to hide iOS App (.plist and .ipa file) on Apache server?

Tags: ios, apache

I have to hide my iOS app on my Apache server (exactly the folder with app and .plist) and I tried with permission (750) but the link for download the app doesn't work:

```
<a href="itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=http://example.com/prova/xxx.plist">Download App</a>
```

How can I hide the folder and in the same permit the download of app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the index module of Apache enabled (which is per default) Apache shows you an index when browsing a directory without an index.html (or similar) file.

To disable this behaviour add the following line to your `.htaccess` file:

```
Options -Indexes
```

If you do not have an `.htaccess` file yet, just create a blank file in the directory you want to hide and the add the line.

If you just want to hide all files with the ending `plist` and `app` from the index add the following line to your .htaccess instead:

```
IndexIgnore *.plist *.app
```